# How To optimise following linq to object query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a enumarable class having following property

```
 Sku

 Itemid

 colorid

 size_id
```

eg:

```
sku1  item1 color1 size1

sku1  item2 color2 size1

sku2  item2 color3 size1
```

here sku can be repeated multiple times

I want to change the structure to something like that
Sku1 comma_seperated_colors comma_seperated_size

so for sku1 the output should be

sku1 color2,color1 size1

currently I am doing that like

```
   var item3 = (from iq in items2 select new { 
        iq.SKU,
        AllColors = string.Join(",", (from i in items2 where i.SKU == iq.SKU select i.color_class).DefaultIfEmpty().ToArray()),
        AllSizes = string.Join(",", (from i in items2 where i.SKU == iq.SKU select i.size).Distinct().DefaultIfEmpty().ToArray())
        });
```

and then selecting unique skus.
now this is taking very long due to multiple scan that is needed.
Can I make this faster??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, couldn't you use a groupby ?

```
var item3 = items.GroupBy (m => m.SKU)
                 .Select(g => new {
                    SKU = g.Key,
                    colors = string.Join("," , g.Select(m => m.color_class)
                                                .Distinct()),//you could do a .OrderBy(m => m) after the distinct
                    sizes = string.Join(",", g.Select(m => m.size)
                                              .Distinct())//you could do a .OrderBy(m => m) after the distinct
                 });
```

and for the "string" result :

```
var result = item3.Select(m.SKU + " " + m.colors + " " + m.sizes).ToList();
```

or

```
var result = item3.Select(m => string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", m.SKU, m.colors, m.sizes)).ToList();
```